# Is there a reason why the UPPER isn't working in the bash script?

Tags: bash

I am trying to make it so I can use a upper or lower case as the variable read.
here is my code that I did. This is meant to select the model of the server and run the right install file based on the input

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
dir=" "
# ============================================================================
# Set the Product Name
# ============================================================================
MODEL="UNKNOWN"
while [ "$1" = "UNKNOWN" ]; do
    KIND="UNKNOWN"
    echo -n "Enter kind [HPCLD|HBCB]: "
    read KIND
    UPPER="$(echo ${KIND}|tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')"
    case "$UPPER" in
        HPCLD) MODEL="HPCLD" ;;
        HBCB) MODEL="HBCB" ;;
    esac
done

if [ "$1" == "HPCLD" ]; then
    echo "Preparing to installation HPCLD applications...."
    cd hpcld
    dir="$(pwd)"
    echo $dir
    echo "./install_hpcld.sh"
else
    echo "Preparing to installation HBCB applications...."
    cd hbcb
    dir="$(pwd)"
    echo $dir
    echo "./install_hbcb.sh"
fi
```

Comment: Your condition should probably be: `while [ "$MODEL" = "UNKNOWN" ]; do` -- and similarly further down, use `"$MODEL"` in your `if`.

Comment: what do you mean by `isn't working`?  does `echo "${UPPER}"` show lowercase letters?  Or is `MODEL` not getting set by the `case` statement? what's the value of `$1` ... not sure how the test (`while [ "$1" = "UNKNOWN" ]`) will ever change since `$1's` value never changes

Answer (score 0):

The main reason it isn't working is that you wrote `"$1"` instead of `"$MODEL"` on the `while` statement.